# Are nested dictionaries slow?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, .net-core

I have a set of data that I should be able to filter by two keys, which are strings.
So I've been wondering what is the faster way to do it.

The most obvious way is a nested dictionary

`Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Data>>`

but I've been also thinking about either using a tuple

`Dictionary<(string, string), Data>`

or combining the strings to create a key

```
string.Format("{0}:{1}", key1, key2)
Dictionary<string, Data>
```

Now this option I doubt is faster, since every lookup is gonna be coupled with the formatting of the key

There's also the option of creating a struct, which will act as the key

```
dataKey(key1, key2)
Dictionary<dataKey, data>
```

Or maybe for such case something else than a dictionary would be a better fit?
In that case I'd add that in the actual application, I first search for key1+key2 combination, and if there's no matching data, I find it using only the key2 and use a placeholder key1.

Comment: `are nested citionaries slow` - .... define _slow_. compared to what? in what use case? and: have you tried benchmarking it yet? my suggestion: just pick whichever feels more _natural_ to you, and worry about optimising performance when you actually _get a performance problem_

Comment: This calls for mr. Lippert's [obligatory performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). Thinking and wondering are no substitutes for benchmarking.

Comment: I've specified the use case and the alternatives that I came up with in the post.

Comment: How many `key1` vs `key2` do you have? If it's very few top-level keys then the first approach makes more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested dictionary lookup is a 2 lookup operations.
If you combine your two keys into one, you will avoid the second lookup operation, at the cost of a new string allocation.

It should be more efficient to have a specific structure as key that contain the two keys, and to implement `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()`

But as said by Jeroen, you should write you own benchmarks with tools like Benchmarkdotnet for real figures.